# Аннотация для выводов логов методов при помощи прокси

Tags: java

Как создать аннотацию, которая выводила бы логи для любого метода, при помощи прокси.

```
public class Test {

@LogMethodData
public int sum(int first, int second) {
    return first + second;
}}
```

а на выводе было что то вроде:

```
янв 26, 2019 5:01:42 PM com.qwerty.classboot.Test sum
```

Comment: Аннотация ничего не значит если её ставить на метод.

Comment: Но при создании кастомной аннотации можно указать для чего она используется:@Target(value=ElementType.METHOD)

Comment: Если вы используете spring, вы можете написать свой аспект, обрабатывающий вашу аннотацию, если у вас стек java EE, можно написать interceptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример создания прокси через cglib.

Аннотация:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LogMethodData {
}
```

Класс для проверки:

```
public class MyClass {
    @LogMethodData
    public String method1() {
        return "this is method1";
    }

    public String method2() {
        return "this is method2";
    }
}
```

Пример программы:

```
import net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer;
import net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;

public class App {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        MyClass myClass = (MyClass) proxyWrapper(new MyClass());
        System.out.println(myClass.method1());
        System.out.println(myClass.method2());
    }

    private static Object proxyWrapper(Object instance) {

        MethodInterceptor handler = (obj, method , args, proxy) -> {
            Annotation annotation = method.getAnnotation(LogMethodData.class);
            if(annotation != null){
                Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(instance.getClass());
                logger.info(method.getName());
            }
            return proxy.invoke(instance, args);
        };

        return Enhancer.create(instance.getClass(), handler);
    }
}
```

Comment: log4j, выдает предупреждения при логировании: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.andrey.logan.MyClass).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Comment: А как вы его настраиваете? У вас есть в проекте что-то похожее на log4j.properties?